# Use $wp_customize->add_control to create a selectable "Designed/Powered By" choices select w/ link in footer?

Tags: array, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use the Customizer controls to create a "Designed By [name]" dropdown menu, and have it echo out the name of the person/group with their name as a link to that website in the footer. This is what I have in my customizer.php, but I'm not sure how to incorporate a URL:

```
// Add "Designed by" notification in footer
$wp_customize->add_setting(
'powered_by',
 array(
  'default' => 'Group 1',
  //'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_powered_by',
  'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
 )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
'powered_by', array(
'section'  => 'footer_section',
'label'    => __( 'Designed by' ),
'type'     => 'select',
'priority' => 8,
'choices'  => array(
    'group1' => __( 'Group 1', 'ctotheme' ),
    'group2' => __( 'Group 2', 'ctotheme' ),
    'group3' => __( 'Group 3', 'ctotheme' ),
    'group4' => __( 'Group 4', 'ctotheme' )
  )
 )
);
```

And I have this in my footer.php:

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'hide_powered_by' ) == false) { ?>
  Designed by <a href="#" target="_blank"><?php echo get_theme_mod( 'powered_by' ); ?></a>.
<?php } // end hide_powered_by if ?>
```

I want the output to be:
Designed by [Group 1](http://link-associated-with-group.com/).

For now, it currently outputs as:
"Designed by group1" instead of "Designed by Group 1"... it's using the word before the => instead of the label after.

Any insight on how to make this work? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this**

```
'group1' => __( 'Group 1', 'ctotheme' ),
```

**To this**

```
'Group 1' => __( 'Group 1', 'ctotheme' ),
```

The first text 'group1' is the value the second is the label for the select option